# How to traverse a list of the following conditions

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
a = [(2,3),(4,1),(2,8),(2,1),(3,4)]
```

How to traverse a list of the following conditions

1. according to the first tuple from small to large order
2. If the first tuple in accordance with the same first two descending order

I can sort it using Python sorted like this:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda d: d[0], reverse=True)
```

but how to make it like this (pseudocode):

```
if d[0] == d[0] then sort list by d[1] reverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(..., key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's answer works well for numbers which seems to be what the OP needs. If the unary `-` can't be applied to the field to be reversed, you can use the `Reversinator`

eg.

```
class Reversinator(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return other.obj < self.obj

a = [(2,'3'),(4,'1'),(2,'8'),(2,'1'),(3,'4')]

print sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0], Reversinator(x[1])))
```